# Use 'alt' value to set 'title' value dynamically in img

Tags: jquery, html

i have lots of images in asp

```
  <img src="site.com/img" class="post-image" alt="a long description"/>
<img src="site.com/img_1" class="post-image" alt="a long description2"/>
```

there is no title in image tag. i need to use alt text to set title of each image. I am using jquery to achieve this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('img').attr('title',$(this).attr('alt'));

</script>
```

Its not working, Am I missing something. please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` in your code does not refers the `img` element. You need to use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) setter that takes a [callback as the argument](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('img').attr('title', function(){
        return $(this).attr('alt')
    });
})
```

Comment: Don't let down votes get you down. Just worry about posting good answers with good explanations and you'll be alright.

Comment: @3dgoo always there will be room for improvement, so just wanted to know whether I missed anything from the dowonvoter if he/she knows a better way

Answer (score 3):

Just try like this.

```
$('.post-image').each(function() {
    this.title = this.alt;
})
```